# Location of information sent by POST to a php file via HTTPRequestObject.send function

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Where does the HTTPRequestObject place strings I have sent via "POST" to a php file?  I have tried looking in the $_POST and $_REQUEST arrays.

I am using send like follows:

request.send("name="+name+"&comment="+comment);

from javascript to send data to a php file, where I loose it.  The request goes though (I check with onreadystatechange), and I'm using the POST method in my open call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

before `request.send()`

and you should replace:

```
request.send("name="+name+"&comment="+comment);
```

with:

```
request.send("name="+encodeURIComponent(name)+"&comment="+encodeURIComponent(comment));
```

Answer (score 0):

"form-urlencoded" does not refer to an associative array.  I think "request.send("name="+name+"&comment="+comment);" is correct.